# Pulling variables from text file (powershell)

Tags: powershell, text-files

I have a script that turns out a UI with variable inputs and places these variables into a .txt. I need to be able to call parts of the text file into another script. IE:

Text File Reads
UserID: username

I need to separate this line and call "username" as a variable in another script so the script will read:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$id = "username"
$ADLocation = ($id.ParentContainer)
$hoou = "OU=User,OU=Office,OU=win7,DC=company,DC=corp"
get-aduser $id
Move-ADObject -Identity $ADLocation -TargetPath $hoou
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you store the variables as PowerShell variables in a .ps1 file?

```
$userId = "username"
```

Then you could simply dot-source the file:

```
. C:\path\to\vars.ps1
```

**Update:** Since you can't use PowerShell format you have to parse the input file. If the line with the user information looks like you mentioned above

> UserID: username

you could do something like this to extract the username and assign it to a variable:

```
$username = Get-Content C:\vars.txt `
              | ? { $_ -match '^\s*UserID:\s*' } `
              | select -First 1 `
              | % { ($_ -split ':\s*', 2)[1] }
```

Comment: I wish but this is pulling from an existing .txt that is used across the company for other applications. We also use the .txt for some manual processes.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am having trouble understanding what it is you are actually asking for here. The question does not make a lot of sense to me.
2. Storing data you need to call later in a txt file is OK, but you should consider storing it in a CSV instead. PowerShell supports exporting and importing CSV files using the Import-Csv and Export-Csv commands.

Comment: I guess to simplify my question I have a variable that is stored in a text file. The line looks like this

UserID: username

I need to grab just username from this line and turn it into a variable 

P.S. csv would make this easier but for now I have to keep using our company's SOP for logging which this will turn into once I get a little better at this. Thanks for the suggestion though.